# C# textbox read-only dependant on other text

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a windows form application with 3 text boxes, if the text in the first text box is 0, the other two text boxes are set to read only, if 1, only the last text box is read only, and if 2, all text boxes are editable.

My code works, but if I enter a value and then change it the program crashes, how can I solve this?

here is my code for the first Text box (NumberOfTusks) which changes the read-only property of (Tusk1Length) and (Tusk2Length) dependant on the value.

```
private void NumberOfTuskstxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
            if (int.Parse(NumberOfTuskstxt.Text) == 0)
            {
                Tusk1Lengthtxt.Text = "N/A";
                Tusk1Lengthtxt.ReadOnly = true;
                Tusk2Lengthtxt.Text = "N/A";
                Tusk2Lengthtxt.ReadOnly = true;
            }
            else if (int.Parse(NumberOfTuskstxt.Text) == 1)
            {
                Tusk1Lengthtxt.Text = "";
                Tusk1Lengthtxt.ReadOnly = false;
                Tusk2Lengthtxt.Text = "N/A";
                Tusk2Lengthtxt.ReadOnly = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Tusk1Lengthtxt.Text = "";
                Tusk1Lengthtxt.ReadOnly = false;
                Tusk2Lengthtxt.Text = "";
                Tusk2Lengthtxt.ReadOnly = false;
            }
    }
```

If I enter 1 into NumberOfTusks and then change the value to 2, the code crashes and gives me this ""An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"" 
The crash happens after i hit backspace. how can I fix this so that if i change the value it doesn't crash?

Comment: Are you changing it to something other than a number? That's going to cause you issues for sure. You should at least use `int.TryParse` instead of assuming your input is going to be an integer every time.

Comment: the input stays an int. It crashes if i change from 1 to 2.

Comment: No, your comment is wrong. The input does not stay an int. You are deleting a character in the process, so before you've set the input to 2, it has become `""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the error is occurring when you hit backspace and are effectively doing

```
 if (int.Parse("") == 0)
```

That will be what's throwing the format exception. I'd suggest you check something like

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NumberOfTuskstxt.Text))
{
  //Your existing code goes here
}
else
{
  //Handle the blank textbox
}
```

To piggyback off [DangerZone's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2957232/dangerzone) comment you'll probably want to also use TryParse rather than Parse to guard against non-numeric user input.